# NgrxPipe in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ngrx

Is this possible? I've tried `npm i github:ngrx/component-builds.git` but I still get the error that the NgrxPush pipe could not be found.

I also get the warnings that it needs a peer of `@angular/common^10.0.0` and `@angular/core^10.0.0`. Is this just not available yet in Ionic until Angular 10 is implemented?

The error:

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found!
Error: The pipe 'ngrxPush' could not be found!
    at getPipeDef$1 (core.js:36858)
    at ɵɵpipe (core.js:36816)
    at ClockInButtonComponent_Template (template.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12156)
    at renderView (core.js:11926)
    at renderComponent (core.js:13505)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:11727)
    at renderView (core.js:11952)
    at renderComponent (core.js:13505)
    at renderChildComponents (core.js:11727)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:963)
    at ionic-angular.js:2338
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:364)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:41654)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:363)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:123)
    at NgZone.run (core.js:41427)
    at AngularFrameworkDelegate.attachViewToDom (ionic-angular.js:2337)
    at attachComponent (framework-delegate-d1eb6504.js:3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the `ReactiveComponentModule` module?

Comment: I did not... that was the problem indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's just telling to install it with `npm i github:ngrx/component-builds.git`